# Bootstrap datepicker data binding with angular 4 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-datepicker

I have used bootstrap datepicker to get the donation date for users in my blood donation app. After the user clicks on input box the calendar pops and user can select the date however I get the same null value. But if I select the cursor into that text field and press some key like space, it reads the value and binding works. How can I fix this issue. Please help

```
                <h3 class="h2">Your Next Donation Schedule</h3>
            <div class="form-group datepicker">
                <label for="datepicker">Last Donated</label>
                <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" class="form-control" value="date" data-provide="datepicker"  [(ngModel)]="date">
            </div>
```

And in my angular app constructor

```
this.date = null;
```

And I have a submit button that passes the date value to the function. If I see console log the date value after selecting date from inside the function, it is still null because it has not changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the boostrap datepicker, but you might want to consider using:

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DateBox/Overview/Angular/Light/